# Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() is always returning 1 on Container-Optimized OS

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm deploying elasticsearch on kubernetes engine on GCP and running into aperformance issue. Elasticsearch determines the size of various thread pools based on the number of cores. Even though I have an 32 core VM created, the thread pool size is just 1.

I did write a test program to print the `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` and it just prints as 1.

I guess it has something to do with the "Container-Optimized OS" which is the only OS allowed on the VMs using Kubernetes Engine. When i create an Debian VM on GCP the `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` returns 8. Not sure how is elasticsearch is being used on the GCPs kubernetes engine. Any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

When i create an Debian VM on GCP without kubernetes, the `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` returns 8.

Comment: Elasticsearch version used is 7.2

Comment: And what does `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l` show in such system ? Is it consistent with what you obtained using `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` ?

Comment: Another question: Are this methods run within the container or directly on one of the Compute Engine VMs forming the GKE kubernetes cluster ?

Comment: The "cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l" returns 32. But the Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() returns just "1". These were executed within the container.

Comment: So I would say it is rather JVM issue. For some reason those Java methods don't detect something which is available from system perspective as if from JVM perspective only 1 core was available.

Comment: _"Container-Optimized OS" which is the only OS allowed on the VMs using Kubernetes Engine_ - I can see that you can choose also Ubuntu when setting up new GKE cluster.

Comment: Just came across this question as I am having the exact same issue - I have a 32 core bare metal server running Kubernetes 1.15 and `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` only reports 1, which is severely impacting the number of threads I start.

Comment: I found this related blog post: [CPU considerations for Java applications running in Docker and Kubernetes](https://medium.com/@christopher.batey/cpu-considerations-for-java-applications-running-in-docker-and-kubernetes-7925865235b7) – it states that new Java versions take the CPU limit of Docker/Kubernetes and divide it by 1024 to obtain the "number of cores". Can you check?

Answer (score 7):

you can try

> -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=[host_cpu_count]

and then

> Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()

will return

> host_cpu_count

Comment: Good find.  However, my research indicates that this was only added in Java 11.

Comment: java 8 also have the option

Comment: Hmm ... OK.  I was searching the source code in the openjdk jdk8u tree and I couldn't find it.  Don't know why.