# java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() : difference beween java 8 (ncpus=32) and java 11 (ncpus=1)

Tags: java, version, cpu, cpu-architecture

When I used a program, on our linux cluster, that needed the number of cpus on my machine I was surprised to see that the number detected by java (ncpus=1) was different from nproc  (ncpus=32)

```
nproc
32
```

so I wrote a minimal program to test this:

```
import java.lang.management.*;
public class Test {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
     OperatingSystemMXBean op = (OperatingSystemMXBean)ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
    System.err.println("A - CPUS: " + op.getAvailableProcessors());
    System.err.println("B - CPUS: " + java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    }
}
```

so using **JAVA** **11**

```
    $ java -version  && javac Test.java && java Test
    openjdk version "11.0.8-internal" 2020-07-14
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8-internal+0-adhoc..src)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8-internal+0-adhoc..src, mixed mode)
    A - CPUS: 1
    B - CPUS: 1
```

but using **JAVA 8** returns the expected result:

```
$ java -version  && javac Test.java && java Test
openjdk version "1.8.0_112"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.19.0.1-linux64) (build 1.8.0_112-b16)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.19.0.1-linux64) (build 25.112-b16, mixed mode)
A - CPUS: 32
B - CPUS: 32
```

why do  I get two different number for two different java versions ? why does java 11 looks wrong ?

Comment: Is this by chance inside of a container? AFAIK there's been a change regarding container-awareness where old JVMs might report the physical number of CPUs and new ones might report the number reserved for your container. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57003259/runtime-getruntime-availableprocessors-is-always-returning-1-on-container-op

Comment: Not the answer, but note that you are running JVMs from two different vendors: OpenJDK 11 and Zulu 8. Why does the 11 version have an `-internal` suffix?

Comment: Can you try adding `-XX:ActiveProcessorCount=32` jvm argument when you run?

Comment: @ellis `java -version  && javac Test.java && java -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=32 Test
openjdk version "11.0.8-internal" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8-internal+0-adhoc..src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8-internal+0-adhoc..src, mixed mode)
A - CPUS: 32
B - CPUS: 32
`

Comment: @Pierre: I didn't downvote your question and downvoters are not required to provide feedback, but if I had to guess then I'd say because there's already many questions about this kind of problem (like the one I linked above).

Comment: @knittl nice point. I'll check it it works with another jdk version.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I asked our sysadmain, I'm waiting for his answer.

Comment: @knittl same problem with jdk19 `$ java -version && javac Test.java  && java Test
openjdk version "19.0.2" 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 19.0.2+7-44)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.2+7-44, mixed mode, sharing)
A - CPUS: 1
B - CPUS: 1
`

Comment: @JoachimSauer so my sysadmin replied: my sysadmin replied: "there is no container. But we run `cgroups`: it works more or less well"

Comment: @Pierre: cgroups is the same feature that containers use to restrict access to some resources, so it's quite possible that you're hitting the same logic that applies to containers in the JVM.